# Can't put a window in a style (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the feeling that I am missing something very important. I've created the following code:

File: App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="HelloWorld.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Startup="Application_Startup">
    <Application.Resources>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="MainView.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

File: MainWindow.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:HelloWorld.ViewModel">
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:ViewModel}">
        <Window Title="HelloWorld">
            <Window.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="50"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </Window.Resources>
            <TextBlock Text="TODO" />
        </Window>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Although I can compile the code and everything looks good. I get the grey wiggly lines from `<Window Title="HelloWorld">` to `</Window>` with the message "Can't put a Window in a Style.". I am wondering what did I do wrong?

What should I do to improve my code? I am btw trying to use the MVVM.

Thanks!

Comment: Can window be styled at all in wpf? There are no control what can have content set to display window. If you want customize window appearance (or have common parts, shared between all windows), then you can create custom control.

Comment: Well, this is just an example case demonstrating my problem. I see the TextBlock and the margins that I set, so if you refer to "styled" as this, then yes. Otherwise I am not sure what you are referring to. Second I think this might have something to do with the datacontext. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You can create `DataTemplate` of window **content**. It can be `Grid` to example (but normally `UserControl`), for which you set `Margin`. Then window will simply use `ContentControl` as content, which `Content` can be bound to to VM (and will display `Grid`).

Comment: Where is the sense in having a Window in a DataTemplate? Please explain what you want to achieve, because that isn't clear from your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Window` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Provides the ability to create, configure, show, and manage the lifetime of windows and dialog boxes.

and:

> is primarily used to display windows and dialog boxes for standalone applications.

As `Window` elements are top-level elements, they cannot be added into the `Content` of lower level elements. Your *Can't put a Window in a Style* error is clear... you cannot use a `Window` in a `Style`, or in a `DataTemplate` in your case.

Instead of attempting that, you have a couple of choices:

1) Put the `Window` contents into a `DataTemplate` and then display that content in a `ContentControl` in a `Window`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:ViewModel}">
    <!-- Define content -->
</DataTemplate>
```

...

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ViewModelProperty}" />
```

2) Use a `UserControl` instead of a `Window` element:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:ViewModel}">
    <UserControl>
        <!-- Define Content here -->
    </UserControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: So I've created a new window file let's call it TestWindow.xaml, but I can't seem to bind it to the MainWindow.xaml which contains the DataTemplate. Could you maybe indicate what the ViewModelProperty is?

Comment: In my example, `ViewModelProperty` is a property in any custom object that has been set as the `Window.DataContext` and is of your `ViewModel` type. That is how the data is passed from the view model to the `DataTemplate` via the `ContentControl`.